# VSO build definition - run build artifact from a command line task - path issue

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm having a path issue.

- Is there a way for me to access the remote command line for my build instance? It sure would help me debug this scenario.
- I can't repro the *The system cannot find the path specified* message locally. Does VSTS validate paths specified as arguments in a build task?
- Is there a better approach for running a build artifact with a command line argument that is the path to a file it will use?

## -----My scenario-----

I've got a build definition task that successfully publishes an artifact called metadatapreprocessor.exe to the artifacts location. Here's what the publish to artifacts task looks like:

### Task 1 - publish executable to artifacts location (success)

**Path to Publish**:

Task#1: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MetadataPreprocessorRunner/bin/Debug/MetadataPreprocessor.exe`

**Artifact Name**: MetadataPreprocessor
[image]

I've got a command line task to run the artifact named MetadataPreprocessor.exe:

### Task 2 - run the executable in artifacts staging area with input file (fail)

**Tool**:
`$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\MetadataPreprocessor\MetadataPreprocessor.exe`
**Arguments**: `--MetadataRelativePathFromFileSystem=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\submodules\Graph_Metadata\input_metadata.xml`

[image]

It appears that I'm properly referencing the executable in the staging area as I'd expect to a see *MetadataPreprocessor.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command...* if I wasn't finding that executable.

Comment: I ended up running the executable from the SourcesDirectory and passing in the argument from the SourceDirectory. I skipped using the artifacts all together. I'm wondering now if I was using the artifacts in an unsupported way.

Answer (score 1):

You are publishing the files to the server, so it isn’t in the artifact folder ($(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)), that’s why it can’t find the path specified.

You can add **Copy Files task** to copy the files from sources directory to artifact folder. (Source Folder: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`; Contents:`**\MetadataPreprocessor.exe`; Target Folder: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`).